# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'"

Tags: python, kivy, textfield

I'm really confused about why this is happening for only one of my text input fields. I have multiple others that are working fine and although I've looked into similar questions I haven't found an answer that makes sense in my situation. The error I am getting is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'"

main.py

```
class PredictEstimate(Screen):
    children = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submitPatient(self):
        childrenText = self.children.text
        print("Children Text: ", childrenText)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [PredictEstimate(name="predict")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<PredictEstimate>:

    children: children


    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Number of Children: "
            font_size: (40)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "y":0.45}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: children
            font_size: (50)
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "y":0.45}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.68, "y": 0.05}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            font_size: (50)
            background_color: .1, .1, .1, .1
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:
                root.submitPatient()
```

Comment: change `age: ObjectProperty(None)` to `age = ObjectProperty(None)`

Comment: I tried changing it, but now I'm getting the error "File "/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 632, in add_widget
     self.children.insert(0, widget)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'"

Comment: Do you know what that might be referring to?

Comment: No, if you want help then provide a [MRE]

Comment: I only changed the line you told me to, but I edited it in the above code

Comment: If you do not provide an MRE then your questions are off-topic so I will vote to close it.

Comment: I only made the change that you suggested I make, I'm really confused at what you do not approve of? I've removed some of the other lines if that's what you mean? I only included them thinking they were part of the MRE in order to show that I did others the same way that are working 100%, just trying to be thorough.

Comment: 1) My initial comment is only to correct an error that was obvious and has nothing to do with an MRE. 2) Have you read the link provided to you? It seems not. An MRE is a code that allows the community to make a copy-paste and then execute it obtaining the same error you get, and that clearly goes against pieces of codes that nobody can execute. In conclusion, read the link where it clearly indicates that it is an MRE that allows us to reproduce your problem and therefore analyze it and provide you with possible solutions.

Comment: plus: `childrenText = self.children.tex` --- > `childrenText = self.children.text`

Comment: The missing t was a typo. I'm a student, not an expert, and I'm honestly just trying to get help about a problem I don't understand, so that I am better educated next time the problem comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The Widget class has the [`children`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.children) property that is used to store the widgets children, and therefore any class that inherits from Widget such as Screen and PredictEstimate will have it but you are overriding it with a None generating the error that you indicate.

#### Solution:

Do not use children but another name for that attribute:

**main.py**

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class PredictEstimate(Screen):
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submitPatient(self):
        childrenText = self.text_input.text
        print("Children Text: ", childrenText)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("login.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [PredictEstimate(name="predict")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

**login.kv**

```
<PredictEstimate>:
    text_input: text_input

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"Number of Children: "
            font_size: (40)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "y":0.45}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            font_size: (50)
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "y":0.45}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.68, "y": 0.05}
            size_hint:0.3,0.1
            font_size: (50)
            background_color: .1, .1, .1, .1
            text: "Submit"
            on_release:
                root.submitPatient()
```